# Como puedo mandar una colección de registro registros desde una vista al controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Buenas tardes,

tengo la siguiente vista

```
@model Proyecto_Rercursos_Humanos.Models.Tbl_Horario

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Horario Empleado";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PageDesign.cshtml";

    List<Proyecto_Rercursos_Humanos.Models.Tbl_Horario> Horario = new List<Proyecto_Rercursos_Humanos.Models.Tbl_Horario>();

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container">

        <!--Encabezado-->
        <h2 class="header center grey-text">Horas Extras de Empleados</h2>

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="section">
            <h5>Datos Empleado</h5>



            @for (int x = 7, )
            { }
            <!--Campo para datos del empleado-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col l2 s12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate", id="idEmpleado" } })
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpId,"Codigo Empleado", htmlAttributes: new { id = "idEmpleado" })  
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col l4 s12">
                    <input class="validate" id="Nombre" type="text">
                    <label for="Nombre">Nombre:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col l3 s12">
                    <input class="validate" id="Depto" type="text">
                    <label for="Depto">Puesto:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col l3 s12">
                    <input class="validate" id="Depto" type="text">
                    <label for="Depto">Departamento:</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Datos del Horario-->

        <div class="section">
            <h5>Datos Jornada de Trabajo</h5>

            <!--Campos para datos de la jornada de trabajo-->
            <div class="row">
                <!--Select para las jornadas de trabajo-->
                <div class="input-field col l4 s12">
                    @Html.DropDownList("JorId")
                    <label>Jornadas de Trabajo</label>
                </div>

                <!--Select para los turnos de trabajo-->
                <div class="input-field col l4 s12">
                    <select>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un Turno</option>
                        <option value="1">Turno A</option>
                        <option value="2">Turno B</option>
                        <option value="3">Turno C</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Turnos de Trabajo</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Seccion del Horario-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <table class="centered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="3">D&iacuteas</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="4">Horario</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Hora Entrada</th>
                            <th>Hora Inicio Descanso</th>
                            <th>Hora Fin Descanso</th>
                            <th>Hora Salida</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia","Lunes", new {@readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia", "Martes", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia", "Miércoles", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia", "Jueves", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia", "Viernes", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia", "Sábado", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBox("HorDia", "Domingo", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraInicioDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraFinDescanso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HorHoraSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timepicker", @placeholder = "Dar clic aquí" } })</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Seccion de Botones-->
        <div class="row center" id="btnGuardar">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar Horario" class="myBtn btn" />  
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

como puedo hacer para mandar de un solo siete filas desde la vista al controlador

Answer (score 0):

Para recibir varios datos con el mismo nombre lo que puedes hacer es recibir un arreglo del tipo de datos que estes definiendo en tu modelo algo como:

```
public ActionResult RecibirFechas(string[] HorHoraFinDescanso,string[] HorHoraSalida)
{
    return View();
}
```

o si lo quieres hacer con  una clase puedes definir una solo para recibir ese tipo de datos :

```
public class PruebaFechasEnviar
{
    public string[] HorHoraFinDescanso{ get; set; }
    public string[] HorHoraSalida{ get; set; }
}
public ActionResult RecibirFechas(PruebaFechasEnviar FechasRecibidas)
{
    return View();
}
```